# Reading XML Into A DataTable - System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need to be able to do this with a file where I don't necessarily know what the name of elements will be, or how many children they will have (ie:how many columns the dataTable will have).  However, it should be formatted like:

```
<Items>
   <Item>
      <Price>25</Price>
      <Name>Basketball</Name>
   </Item>
   <Item>
      <Price>29</Price>
      <Name>Football</Name>
   </Item>
</Items>
```

I've tried this:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(file.PostedFile.InputStream, XmlReadMode.InferSchema);
```

And This:

```
ds.Tables[0].ReadXml(file.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

But I keep getting "System.Xml.XmlException: Root element is missing."

Comment: From your sample xml `DataSet` is created without any problems (well, actually you are missing closing Price tag, but I think its typo)

Comment: To troubleshoot, try reading the file into a string and taking a look at what comes in: `string troubleshoot = new StreamReader(file.PostedFile.InputStream).ReadAllText();`

Comment: @Alfie - `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` is not the root element. That structure is called the 'XML Declaration'. In the example above - the `<Items>` element is the root element.

Comment: @maembe - You are likely getting this error because the InputStream is empty. Use John's suggestion to troubleshoot and confirm that you're successfully reading in the file's contents.

Comment: @John Sauders - This was it, I was copying the stream to a memory stream for something else before calling ReadXml.

Comment: @maembe: you should give that as the answer to your own question. Show an example of the code that read into a memory stream, just to show what not to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having is that the Input Stream was empty.  I was copying the stream to a MemoryStream earlier:

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
using (Stream s = file.PostedFile.InputStream)
{
     s.CopyTo(memStream);
}
```

In the case of xml docs, this wasn't necessary (it was being used for excel), so I simply only did this if the uploaded file was xls or xlsx.